# Sending a variable from ActionListener, so another ActionListener can use it

Tags: java, variables, scope, actionlistener

I see there are some questions already asked about this topic but I haven't come up to an answer for my. I am writing a code where user types something in `JTextField`, and after clicking a button, his word is replaced with the number of asterisks with the same number of characters his word had e.g "table" would be replaced by "****". i did it this way:

```
ask.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String guess = "";
        String given = textGive.getText();
        for (int i=0; i<given.length(); i++){
            String asterisk = "*";
            guess += asterisk;
            textGive.setText(guess);
        }

    }
});
```

I know that I did not do this in a great way, but I did not know how to do it better. Any recommendations?

Now, I want somehow to save both Strings, the original word and the asterisk one outside the scope so I can access it in another ActionListener and modify it further.
Before writing first `ActionListener` i did write `String guess = ""` and `String given = ""` but it seems as it did not do anything.
So, in my second `ActionListener` i want to send him the string `given` I received when the user typed his word.

```
guess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String attempt = textGuess.getText();
        char att = attempt.charAt(0);
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){

            if (given.charAt(i)==att){
                textGuess.setText("Ok!");
            }
        }


    }
});
```

Eclipse gives me error saying:

> "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable given defined in an enclosing scope".

I understand that I need to make `given` final in order to acces it further, but how to do that if the variable depends on text input from first `ActionListener`? Is there some other solution for this problem? I've recently started using java, so I do not know the language so well.

Comment: Just use fields not local variables!

Comment: what do you want to achieve in the first place? What you describe here sound to me like you want to do some passwort textfield or the like?

Comment: One recommendation, the line `textGive.setText(guess);` should be placed outside the for loop.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to make something like a hangman, user tries to guess the word hidden behind asterisks. Everything works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that you want visible to class should be placed in instance fields, not in local variables. For instance, the given variable should be a private non-static field declared in the class, and not a variable buried within your listener's actionPerformed method.

e.g.,

```
public class Foo extends JPanel {
    private JButton ask = new JButton("Ask");
    private JTextField textGive = new JTextField(10);
    private String given = "";  // visible throughout the class

    public Foo() {
        add(textGive);
        add(ask);
        ActionListener listener = e -> {
            String guess = "";
            // String given = textGive.getText(); //visible only within this method
            given = textGive.getText();
            guess = given.replaceAll("\\w", "*");
            textGive.setText(guess);
        };

        ask.addActionListener(listener);
        textGive.addActionListener(listener);  // also give the same listener to the JTextField
    }
```

Comment: In "English", that means declaring variable before creating a constructor, right?

Comment: @Puki: No. It matters not **where** you declare the variable. It can be before or after the constructor, but it must be at the class level.

Comment: Yes, I meant that, but not told it well. Anyway, it works now. Thanks for the help. Cheers!